# How to get view from fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

From my fragment I need to access view element with `findViewById()`. If I get the view reference by calling `this.getView().findViewById()`, it works but as soon I finish activity and try again it stops from working.

What I have done is to get View reference from saving it from LayoutInflater. And it works.

What I want to know is why it doesn't work the way I have done it before? And if in activities, it is ok to access view with `getView().findViewById().`

I am a little confused.

Comment: "as soon I finish activity and try again it stops from working." This part is confusing.Can you post code example and describe step by step what you do?

Comment: What I would like to know is how to cover all possible cases if activity is closed and then recreated with accessing its view. So if activity is closed and its resources are needed so it is removed, or for an example if you lock your phone and don't use it for few hours and then you open app again. Should you do any check if view is null or not or just access it from this.getView()?

Comment: When Activity is recreated you have to create views again, also those for your fragment. If you need some UI states to be persisted, store them in onSaveInstanceState() of your fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getView()`, but you have to be sure that the view has been created, which is not always the case during the fragments lifecycle.
it should only be there from the inflation in `OnCreateView` till `onDestroyView()`.

Saving a reference is a good way, but always check for null before accessing it.
A good place to get a reference would be `onViewCreated`. You can use the view object there.

Take a look in here for some more lifecycle insight:
http://www.silverbaytech.com/2014/03/24/android-fragment-lifecycle-in-detail/